# Return Array of Populated Objects in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have a DB for a forum with 3 collections: Threads, Posts, Comments.
I have a GET request to return an **individual** forum thread that populates each thread with user's posts, and each user post with any comments that were made on it which is working as shown below:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
   Threads
  .findById(req.params.id)
  .lean()
  .populate({path: 'posts'})
  .exec(function(err, docs){

 var options = {
   path: 'posts.comments',
   model: 'comments'
 };

   if(err) return res.json(500);
   Threads.populate(docs, options, function(err, thread){
     res.json(thread);
   })
  })
 })
```

When this GET request is made it will return a forum thread like so:

```
  {
  "_id": "5924ad549a08ed4e70a9c89f",
  "title": "Testing Full Schemas",
  "author": "Mongoose",
  "content": "Schema Content",
  "posts": [
    {
      "_id": "5924ad999a08ed4e70a9c8a0",
      "content": "New Schema Post",
      "user": "Mongodb",
      "comments": [
        {
          "_id": "5924ae489a08ed4e70a9c8a1",
          "comment": "New Schema Content",
          "user": "Matt",
          "likes": 0,
          "created": "2017-05-25T12:41:58.319Z"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now I need a GET request to return an array of **ALL** threads (router.get('/')) with each threads posts and comments to be populated.  I tried to replace:

```
      Threads
      .findById(req.params.id)
```

with

```
    Threads
    .find(req.params.id)
```

but it is not working.  Does anyone have an idea of how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return all the threads, simply use `find` without any `match condition` in it.
Also, `populate posts` and `'posts.comment'` in the `find` query itself, you don't need to do it in the `callback` of the `find`.

use population across multiple levels

**Try this:

```
Threads.find({})
.populate({
    path:'posts',
    populate :{
        path : comments
    }
})
.exec(function(err,docs){
    //docs is the array of all the Threads, with posts and comments populated within it
})
```

Read [Mongoose Documentation on Populate and Nested Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for detailed information. ( Search for **Populating across multiple levels**)

Answer (score 0):

**findById** and **findOne** returns a single document, where **find** returns a cursor. Once you go through the cursor of find, you are at the end, and there are no more documents.

Using find query:-

```
    ModelName.find({_id:req.params.id})
    .populate({
        path:'posts',
        populate :{
            path : comments
        }
    },(error,data)=>{
    if(error){
       res.json(error);
}
else{
res.json(data);
}
})
```

Using findById query:-

```
    ModelName.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate({
        path:'posts',
        populate :{
            path : comments
        }
    },(error,data)=>{
    if(error){
       res.json(error);
}
else{
res.json(data);
}
})
```